# How to ignore null fields in json serialization (Newtonsoft.Json)?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an object which contains multiple instances of iList, iDictionary and objects containing some primitives. I have this code to not include null values, but it does not work on iDictionary. The problem appers only when the object is large.

```
    tw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ic, Formatting.None,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    }));
```

The object

```
IC
 Header
  int
  string (can be null)
  string
 IList<Component>
  int
  string
  double
  double
  IList<Input>
   int
   int
   int
  IDictionary<string,object> (freqently null, always serialized)
 IDictionary<string,IC> (can be null, always serialized)
```

relevant part of json

```
 {
  "HEADER": {
    "TAG": "PROJECT",
    "APP_VERSION": 91
  },
  "COMPONENTS": [
   {
    "ID": 34509537,
    "TAG": "BUFFER_GATE",
    "X": 870.0,
    "Y": 450.0,
    "INPUTS": [
     {
      "CONNECTOR_ID": 0,
      "OTHER_COMPONENT": 33017225,
      "OTHER_CONNECTOR_ID": 47
    }
  ],
  "ARGUMENTS": null
},...
```

Comment: Do you mean the dictionary itself is null, or there are entries in the dictionary with null values that you don't want to serialize?

Comment: The dictionary itself.

Comment: Can you give an example of some json?

Comment: What happens if you change IC to just contain a IDictionary

Comment: Json: https://pastebin.com/284rMQpG

Comment: Please include the json in your question and not as an external link. You can truncate it so long as it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If I leave only Directory there I will get only the tree sturtructure of the object. I might have looked somewhere else, becouse now I cannot see that IC.IDictionary could be null.

Comment: Ok will make something smaller so ti will fit.

Comment: did nothing and it stopped hapenning. Will proceed to find why it happens.

Comment: It appers it happens only with larger objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the file and recreated it instead of overwriting it. Source object was exactly the same. I was probably not overwriting the file correctly.